# How to route UPnP broadcasts to another subnet?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, upnp

I got my internal subnet 192.168.1.x (255.255.255.0) where is an UPnP server sending broadcasts. 
Machines in this subnet can receive these broadcasts just normally.

There's another VPN subnet, VPN clients get leased addresses in subnet 192.160.0.x (255.255.255.252). These two subnets can communicate without any problems (using routes),
however it seems that UPnP broadcasts cannot pass into this subnet.

So my question is **how do I set a static route so the UPnP broadcasts can pass even into the VPN subnet?**
(so the applications running on the remote machines connected over the VPN can receive these broadcasts.)

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an IGD device, you can setup your linux box to act as one. http://linux-igd.sourceforge.net/documentation.php